# From C# how do I call an unmanaged OLE interface that requires a *VARIANT parameter?

Tags: c#, c++, ole, variant

From C# I am trying to call an OLE interface written in C++. The signatures from the .ODL file of the C++ code are:

```
long GetData1( int* data );
long GetData2( double* data );
long GetData3( VARIANT* data );
```

Here is a sample of my C# code:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IMyInterface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    long GetData1 ( [In, Out] ref int data );
    [DispId(1)]
    long GetData2 ( [In, Out] ref double data );
    [DispId(3)]
    long GetData3 ( [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref IntPtr data);
}
```

GetData1() and GetData2() work fine, but GetData3() results in a "Type Mismatch" exception.

For GetData3() I have tried every combination of In, Out, Ref, MarshallAs(), C# type, etc. I can think of with no success.

Please note the C++ code can not change.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(VS.71).aspx VARIANT is Object

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways to call a function that takes a VARIANT pointer.

The sane method is to declare the parameter as `ref object data` and .NET will marshal for you. [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adam_nathan/2003/04/24/unmanagedtype-struct-and-variant-marshaling/) has more details and a example.

The other method is to create and fill in a VARIANT struct in memory yourself and just pass the address as a IntPtr parameter. This is probably overkill and a VARIANT is big and complicated so the StructLayout for it is not going to be fun.